# Regarding HHTPTrigger to retrieve a document from CosmosDB

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to execute the HTTP Trigger azure function to retrieve a document from CosmosDB. I am trying to pass the id value in the URL, but not able to retrieve the document. I have got this sample code from learn.microsoft.com.

## Function code:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, todoitems: func.DocumentList) -> str:
    if not todoitems:
        logging.warning("ToDo item not found")
    else:
        logging.info("Found ToDo item, Description=%s",
                     todoitems[0]['description'])

    return 'OK'
```

## function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "todoitems",
      "databaseName": "ckdb",
      "collectionName": "cosmocontainer",
      "connectionStringSetting": "ckdb_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "in",
      "id": "{id}",
      "PartitionKey": "{id}"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": true,
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py"
}
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1?id="3"
```

Even though I have the document with id value as "3" in cosmosdb database, function is not able to retrieve the document. Please guide me to fix the error.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it is not enough for cosmosdb to provide only the id, and the partition key must also be provided. I will provide an answer later.

Comment: I have post an answer. Please let me know whether you can work it out or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bowman. As suggested by you, I have included the partition key along with id and it worked. It solved my issue.

Comment: Hi, when the answer posted by a person solves your problem, you should [mark his answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsESi.png) to end the problem. Because only you do this, other people will know that this question already has an answer when they face similar problems and search, which will help others.

Comment: Hi Bowman, Please let me know how to mark an answer. I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: You can find a tick on the left side of my answer. Click it to turn it green. This is mark

Comment: Please follow this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsESi.png

Comment: I have updated the tick. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problems comes from the item in your cosmosdb.

It is not possible to get the specified item by simply providing the id. Multiple items can exist in the same id in a container.

Please have a look of my cosmosdb:

[image]

And this is my azure function:

***init*.py :**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, documents: func.DocumentList) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    if not documents:
        logging.warning("ToDo item not found")
    else:
        logging.info("Found ToDo item")
    return 'OK'
```

**function.json :**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "name": "documents",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "databaseName": "testbowman",
      "collectionName": "testbowman",
      "id" : "1",
      "partitionKey": "1",
      "connectionStringSetting": "MyAccount_COSMOSDB",
      "direction": "in"
  }
  ]
}
```

**local.settings.json :**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "MyAccount_COSMOSDB":"AccountEndpoint=https://testbowman.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=xxxxxx;"
  }
}
```

After i start my function, only item like this can be catch:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "testbowman": "1"
}
```

(This is because I have to provide the value of the partition key while providing the id. In my case, the partition key name is testbowman.)

When you actually use it, you do not need to fix the value to 1, you can specify the value of the corresponding parameter through `{}`.

You can see that I can successfully get here:

[image]